# Python - Using csv and xlrd module to write multi-row excel file to one row csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlrd

I've got a basic script that will take a source excel (.xlsx) file and write the data to a matching csv file in python.  My ultimate goal is take all of the data in a sheet and write it one long comma seperated row and I'm not sure how to accomplish that based on what I have so far.

```
def csv_from_excel():
    import csv
    import xlrd
    wb1 = raw_input('What is the path and file name of your Workbook? ')
    sh = raw_input('What is the name of the sheet being transformed? ')
    csv_file1 = raw_input('What is the file path and name of the output? ')
    print wb1
    print sh
    print csv_file1
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(wb1)
    sh1 = wb.sheet_by_name(sh)
    csv_file = open(csv_file1, 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh1.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh1.row_values(rownum))

    csv_file.close()
    print "Completed converting %s and %s to csv" % (wb1, sh)

csv_from_excel()
```

Comment: You should explain what is wrong with the output of your code. Is it not doing what you expect etc?

Comment: why would you want to do this ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley we are attempting to aggregate a large amount of data into csv format to use a source for Hadoop.

Comment: @TYY The script works well for converting to csv but it keeps the multirow formatting that the source excel file has.  To be clear, the current format of the script is working as I expect it to.  I first wanted to accomplish just converting the xlsx to csv before tackling the harder part of flattening the output.

Comment: hadoop needs it all in one line for some reason? thats strange I guess ... I'm not overly familiar with hadoop

Comment: @JoranBeasley Honestly I'm not sure how hadoop best handles the data as I have not had exposure to it yet.  The engineer that requested the script said he would love it if I could take multiple source files, all formatted the same and flatten them into one csv for hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take a multi-row XLS and output that as a single-row CSV. If so, this is causing you to output multiple CSV rows:

```
for rownum in xrange(sh1.nrows):
    wr.writerow(sh1.row_values(rownum))
```

That code steps through each row in your XLS and creates a corresponding row in your CSV. Since you only want one CSV row, you should probably accumulate the XLS rows into a single collection before writing it all out in a single step:

```
output = list()
for rownum in xrange(sh1.nrows):
    output.extend(sh1.row_values(rownum))
wr.writerow(output)
```